# Why is angular orderBy custom comparator not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-orderby

I am trying to implement a custom comparator for the angular orderBy directive. As you can see in the code snippet, the custom comparator is being ignored (nothing logged from console.log) even though it should work according to the [angular documentation for orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

```js
angular.module('orderByExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.files = [
    {name: 'File1', size: '1.2 Mb'},
    {name: 'File2', size: '2.4 Kb'},
    {name: 'File3', size: '241 Bytes'},
    {name: 'File4', size: '2.0 Mb'},
    {name: 'File5', size: '16.1 Kb'}
  ];

  $scope.fileSizeComparator = function(s1, s2) {
    // split the size string in nummeric and alphabetic parts
    console.log(s1);
    console.log(s2);
    var s1Splitted = s1.size.split(" ");
    var s2Splitted = s2.size.split(" ");
    if (s1Splitted[1] === s2Splitted[1]) {
      // if size type is the same, compare the number
      return s1Splitted[0] > s2Splitted[0];
    }
    // default : compare on size type Mb > Kb > Bytes
    return s1Splitted[1] > s2Splitted[1];
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="orderByExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Size</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="file in files | orderBy:'size':false:fileSizeComparator">
        <td>{{file.name}}</td>
        <td>{{file.size}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tested the example code from the angular documentation on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vdk21c62/) and it's not working either.
Any ideas?

Comment: looking in the last example of angular documentation, it says the 3rd parameter should be read as a function

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the solution after some help from @morels : yes I should indeed return 1 and -1. But the main problem was that the comparator was being ignored. Apparently it is because this feature is only available to angular 1.5.7 and higher.
I also needed to use the `.split` on the `.value` of the passed parameters of s1 and s2.

Here's the working solution in code snippet:

```js
angular.module('orderByExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.files = [
    {name: 'File1', size: '1.2 Mb'},
    {name: 'File2', size: '2.4 Kb'},
    {name: 'File3', size: '241 Bytes'},
    {name: 'File4', size: '2.0 Mb'},
    {name: 'File5', size: '16.1 Kb'}
  ];

  $scope.fileSizeComparator = function(s1, s2) {
    // split the size string in nummeric and alphabetic parts
    var s1Splitted = s1.value.split(" ");
    var s2Splitted = s2.value.split(" ");
    if (s1Splitted[1] === s2Splitted[1]) {
      // if size type is the same, compare the number
      return parseFloat(s1Splitted[0]) > parseFloat(s2Splitted[0]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    // default : compare on size type Mb > Kb > Bytes
    return s1Splitted[1] > s2Splitted[1] ? -1 : 1;
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="orderByExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Size</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="file in files | orderBy:'size':false:fileSizeComparator">
        <td>{{file.name}}</td>
        <td>{{file.size}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you should return `-1,0,1` not `true,false`.

Following the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy#using-a-custom-comparator) you can see **the format** of a typical compare function:

> ```
> $scope.localeSensitiveComparator = function(v1, v2) {
> // If we don't get strings, just compare by index
> if (v1.type !== 'string' || v2.type !== 'string') {
>   return (v1.index < v2.index) ? -1 : 1;
> }
>
> // Compare strings alphabetically, taking locale into account
> return v1.value.localeCompare(v2.value);   };
> ```

Please rewrite as:

```
$scope.fileSizeComparator = function(s1, s2) {
    // split the size string in nummeric and alphabetic parts
    console.log(s1);
    console.log(s2);
    var s1Splitted = s1.size.split(" ");
    var s2Splitted = s2.size.split(" ");
    if (s1Splitted[1] === s2Splitted[1]) {
      // if size type is the same, compare the number
      if ( s1Splitted[0] > s2Splitted[0])
        return 1;
      else 
       return -1;
    }
    // default : compare on size type Mb > Kb > Bytes
    return s1Splitted[1] > s2Splitted[1] ? -1 : 1;
  };
```

Note that you never miss equality i.e. `0`.

Comment: I have found out that the main problem was the angular version. Apparently the custom comparator need angular 1.5.7 to work. Thanks for the help though, I indeed should be returning 1 or -1 instead of true or false.

Answer (score -3):

Do like this

```
ng-repeat="file in files | orderBy: sizeFilter: true"

$scope.sizeFilter=function(file){
        $scope.size = file.size;
        return $scope.size;
};
```

Comment: This introduces a new scope variable "size" for no explained reason. Also completely misses the OP's intent to use the Byte, kb, Mb part of the string.